# Display currentTime of a song in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'd like to know how can I make time constantly update itself. So when I press the play button the seconds start to update automatically from 0:00 to the end , because now it just updates onclick. I am trying to use HTML5 audio and I have successfully managed to get the time updating as a label from this line of code:

```
sound.ontimeupdate = function () { document.getElementById('Time').innerHTML = sound.currentTime.toFixed() }
```

---

But thats not what I need, I would like to get the time attribute in data() to get updated and displayed in the label as shown in my HTML code.

I tried adding an event listener but it did not work... It gets called and every call was logged with console.log but time attribute was not updated

```
let sound = null
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isPlaying: false,
      time: 0,
      duration: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    playMusic () {
      if (!sound) {
        sound = new Audio(require('assets/YES.mp3'))
      }
      this.isPlaying = true
      sound.play()
      // sound.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () { this.time = sound.currentTime.toFixed() })   -- did not work

      this.time = sound.currentTime.toFixed()
    }
```

Html:

```
<label id="Time" @timeupdate>
    { { time } }:{ { duration } }
</label>
```

Comment: When you create a *closure function*, the `this` may become different things accordingly to the context it has been created, and even if you don't bind any object to the function. So, your attempt of listening the event on the `Audio` object may works if you replace the closure function with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): `() => this.time = sound.currentTime.toFixed()`, because here the `this` will (probably) correspond to the Vue instance.

Comment: Thank you, @GustavoSampaio! It worked. Although i got a lot of eslint errors but i guess im going to disable them.

Comment: If you prefer, you can use the alternative way suggested in the @Radu Diță's answer, for prevent the ESLint errors! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `addEventListener` you get a different `this` than you might expect.

Either use `fat arrow`

`sound.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => this.time = sound.currentTime.toFixed() )`

or, the old way, save `this`

```
let that = this
sound.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () { that.time = sound.currentTime.toFixed() })
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just add a generic timer dynamically. You can use a watch to add/remove it like so:

(untested code)

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isPlaying: false,
            time: 0,
            duration: 0,
            intervalId: null,
            sound: null
        };
    },
    watch: {
        isPlaying(isPlaying) {
            if (this.intervalId !== null) {
                clearInterval(this.intervalId);
            }
            if (isPlaying) {
                this.sound.play();
                this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                    this.time = this.sound.currentTime.toFixed();
                }, 500);
            } else {
                this.sound.stop();
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        playMusic() {
            if (!this.sound) {
                this.sound = new Audio(require("assets/YES.mp3"));
            }
            this.isPlaying = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For vue3 script setup

```
<template>
  <audio :src="file.mp3" id="stream" autoplay></audio>
  <span>{{ currentTime }}</span>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onUpdated } from "vue";
const currentTime = ref();
onUpdated(() => {
  let audio = document.getElementById("stream");
  audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
    currentTime.value = audio.currentTime.toFixed();
  });
});
</script>
```